# Insert selected radio values into a specific id of the table- php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in database, and when want to reject or accept someone's application i just select the radio button and send the value to the table in database.

But the problem is that the value is assigned to new row and not to the specific student id. Here is my table as you see there are added 2 new rows getting another id. Here is my code and table:

```
<?php

  $status  = $_POST["status"];
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","form");
  if (!$connect) {
          die('Connect error:'. mysqli_error());
      }
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO students (status) VALUES ('$status')    ");


?>
```

---

```
    idstudents |fname | lname| age | nationality | status
    .....................................................
        1      |Tom   | Bern | 23  | American    | 
        2      |Lily  | Wayne| 24  | British     |
        3      |NULL  | NULL | NULL| NULL        | accepted
```

Comment: you need an update statement not an insert, when you submit the form, you need an update which includes the status and id from your form

Comment: you need to provide other colums value too!

Answer (score 0):

The `INSERT` statement is meant to... Insert a new row. What you need is an `UPDATE` statement, to apply a value to a certain row, which you are going to select using their `idstudents`.

```
$status  = $_POST["status"];
$studentid  = $_POST["studentid"];

...

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE students SET status = '$status' WHERE idstudents = $studentid;");
```

On a side note, always be careful when using $_POST (or other) values entered by the user, if this service is going to be used by other people, you might want to **sanitize them** before inserting them, to avoid potential security breaches.

Comment: When i do like your code it doesn't add anything in the table, but when i put a specific id in place of $studentid it works.

Comment: @user3615781 You need to post the student id in your html form, as well as the status. For example `<input type="hidden" name="studentid" value="2">`

Answer (score 0):

In order to update, you need an UPDATE statment, dont forget to add a `student_id` on the form. Consider this example: (Same Page Process).

```
<?php

$students = array();
$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');

if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['status'])) {
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    foreach($status as $student_id => $status_value) {
        $stmt = $link->prepare('UPDATE students SET status = ? WHERE idstudents = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $status_value, $student_id);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

$query = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM students');
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $students[] = $row;
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <?php foreach($students as $key => $value): ?>
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                Name: <?php echo $value['fname'] . " " . $value['lname']; ?><br/>
                Status: <b><?php echo ($value['status'] != '') ? $value['status'] : 'N/A'; ?></b><br/>
                <input type="radio" name="status[<?php echo $value['idstudents']; ?>]" value="accepted" /> Accepted
                <input type="radio" name="status[<?php echo $value['idstudents']; ?>]" value="rejected" /> Rejected
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

> Note: Since you are using mysqli now, take advantage of parameterized queries. Dont directly use your $_POST values on the query.